# Does git branch -m have side effects for other developers?

Tags: git, merge, branch

We've [already learned how to switch which branch points to what](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848/switch-branch-names-in-git) using `git branch -m`. If I do this, is it going to make life difficult for the other people pulling from my repository?

Say I do a bunch of stuff on a branch `topic1` and then do a

```
git branch -m master old_master
git branch -m topic1 master
git push origin master
```

and then somebody else pulls `master` from the my remote repository, what will they have to do to make everything point to the right place? Will I have to tell everybody to repeat my steps?

Is this akin to the problem of rebasing commits after pushing them and leaving other developers with dangling objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your repo looks like but here's the worst-case scenario.

Suppose your `origin` repository looks like this

```
origin:
o---o---A---B---C  master
```

And your local repository looks like this,

```
JimPuls:
o---o---A---B---C  master, origin/master
         \
          D---E---F topic1
```

Then, after your branch renames your local repository looks like this:

```
JimPuls:
o---o---A---B---C  old_master, origin/master
         \
          D---E---F master
```

Now, when you push `master` to `origin` that'll be a non-fast-forward update.  After the push, the `origin` repository will look like this:

```
origin:
o---o---A...B...C  (B & C are orphaned commits)
         \
          D---E---F master
```

This can be cruel to your friends who may have done commits on top of `C`.  For example, if Sally was working with you her repository may look like this:

```
Sally:
o---o---A---B---C  origin/master
                 \
                  G---H---I master
```

Now, if you do your non-fast-forward push and Sally does a `fetch` her repository will look like this:

```
Sally:
          D---E---F  origin/master
         /
o---o---A---B---C  
                 \
                  G---H---I  master
```

Now Sally has to figure out how to get her work (G, H, I) back into the repository.  If she simply does a merge with `origin/master` then the changes in B and C will be back in the repository (oops!).  Instead, she'll have to `cherry-pick` or `rebase` her G-H-I changes onto `origin/master`.

It's cool that Git lets you do that but it's kind of asking for trouble.  You're really hoping that Sally notices the situation.  This is why you should warn all the other contributors when you do this so they can deal with the change appropriately.

**NOTE:** the above is a worst-case scenario.  If your `topic1` branch departed from `master` at C then that change *is* a fast-forward and there are no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your operations are the same as:

```
# git checkout master
# git reset --hard topic1
# git push origin master
```

And they will have exactly that effect: Everybody else will get the `topic1` branch (it’s named `master` for them, though) and its ancestry up to the point where `master` and `topic1` first diverged. The old `master` branch is then lying around in their repositories and will be garbage collected at some point in the future because nothing points to it anymore.

If `topic1` is a branch that originated from the current `HEAD` of `master` you will be fine here. Otherwise you will get into the “rewriting history” situation which can make a mess of your e.g. your tags. You need to think carefully about what you’re really trying to achieve. Maybe a simple `git merge` will serve you better?