# Rebasing everyone onto changed git history after filter-branch

Tags: git

Our git repo has a bunch of large files in its history that are no longer needed. I want to remove them using the filter-branch technique explained in Pro Git:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery

I'll then use `git push --force all` to send this to our shared repo, as explained here:

[Update a development team with rewritten Git repo history, removing big files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444091/git-filter-branch-to-delete-large-file)

BUT.  Pro Git says I'll need to have everyone rebase since I'm changing history.  We've only sparingly used rebase, usually just as an alternative way to merge.  I can have everyone re-clone, but that's a last resort; several devs have local branches with changes they'd like to keep.

So: What exactly will everyone need to do in our local repositories to rebase onto the newly-changed shared repo?  And do we have to do it once per tracking branch?  Our repo is referred to as origin and the master branch is master, if you want to give step-by-steps (and I'd love it if you would).

Answer (score 19):

The key is for each individual developer not to lose their original reference to `master` until after they've done their rebase.  To do this, have them do a `fetch` (*not* a pull) after the forced push, then for each local branch, do:

```
git rebase --onto origin/master master <local_branch>
```

When that's done, then they can checkout their `master` and update it by:

```
git pull --force
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option.

- Create your rebased master on a branch called `rebased_master` (instead of your original `master`).
- You would than push that branch and have all your developers pull it down and rebase their local branches onto `rebased_master`.  If they rebase them off the equivalent commit from before the rebase, and didn't have any changes to the files you are removing, all *should* be well.
- Once everyone has moved their dev branches to `rebased_master`, you can delete your original `master` and [move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848/switch-branch-names-in-git) `rebased_master` to `master`

note: I haven't tested this, so make sure you have a copy of your repo to restore in case something goes wrong.

Comment: This sounds right - I'll accept it in the morning after it actually works!