# Git: unrecognised branch name

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

In git, I named a branch:  parse()

The name has been accepted, but when merging I get the error:

> git merge parse()
>   bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('

Is it possible to rename a branch? Are there other ways to fix this problem?

Thank you!

Platform:  Linux, bash

Comment: Note that this isn't a git question at all; your shell never runs git because it can't understand what you typed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try merging by putting quotes around the branch name instead, e.g.:

```
git merge 'parse()'
```

You can rename a branch, but it's not so straightforward. Wherever you want to use the branch name, just use quotes (single or double!).

Answer (score 2):

You can rename a branch using :

```
git branch -m 'parse()' your_new_branch_name
```

(see [Switch branch names in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848/switch-branch-names-in-git))

You should also note that using parenthesis in branch names (or any special bash character) will only cause you problems. I would recommend using only `[-_a-zA-Z0-9]` characters.