# How to make a branch the new master while keeping old master as a branch?

Tags: git, github

I have a project where I am building an ecommerce website in 2 different ways, one using react and one just vanilla js. currently the vanilla branch is master and the react branch is called react-version. I would like to switch them and make the react-version the master and vanilla can be called vanillajs-version.

I have looked at some other answers but in those cases the old master is not needed while in my case it is.

Thanks!

**update:**

as suggested in this answer [Switch branch names in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21932/9111239)
, I was able to switch name in the local repository however when I try to push to remote I get an error saying:

> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/tito300/Elegant-T-K-FullStack.git'
>   hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
>   its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
>   'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>   See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

I do not want to integrate them because they are basically different implementation. I branched out very early in the project. any work around?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch branch names in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848/switch-branch-names-in-git)

Comment: Right, all you're doing is renaming branches: renaming master to vanillajs-version, deleting master, then renaming react-version to master.  Read the other answers carefully, you're making changes in two places that really want to agree.

Comment: see the update in the question

Comment: Though it is not a recommended practise but you can push using `git push -f xx xx`. This will force update the remote. REMEMBER - This is going to overwrite your commit history so use with caution.

Comment: A `git pull xx xx` in your case is advisable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following steps:

1. make a new branch named vanillajs-version
2. create pull request from the master branch to vanillajs-version branch
3. Delete the contents of master branch.
4. create a pull request from the react-version branch
       to master branch.
5. delete the react-version branch or keep it as you
       want

Comment: in part 3, do you mean just delete the files or the branch itself?

Comment: you can delete the files if you cannot delete the branch,
the files of master branch will be copied to vanillajs-version branch in step2.