# Swap branch merges in git

Tags: git, merge, branch, branching-and-merging

I want to essentially swap the roles of two branches in a git repo, when it comes to merging. Since there are many potential ways my problem might be resolvable, I'll just explain my circumstances to avoid an X-Y -question:

I'm developing firmware for a device which has gone through several hardware revisions, which require subtle differences (mostly different constants) in the firmware. The (relevant) hardware revisions are "proto2", "proto3" and "proto4". The original main branch is called "master", and that currently corresponds to hardware revision "proto2". Back in the days when "proto3" came along, I made a new branch called (imaginatively) "proto3". I then made the changes related to the new hardware revision to the "proto3" branch, and continued developing in "master" for revision "proto2". This way I could then checkout "proto3", merge "master" into that, and have my "proto3" -compatible firmware with the new features. Since then, "proto4" has appeared which has one more change (literally a one-liner). So now I develop in "master", and then have to always merge changes to "proto3" and "proto4" (this also means that I have to do the development on the older prototype).

Now we're moving to production, and "proto4" will be the production firmware. However, since some of the older prototypes are still quite useful, I'd like to actually swap the roles of the branches, i.e. be able to develop in the branch "proto4" and merge from there to "master" without introducing the hardware related changes done previously to "proto4" back to "master".

In other words, otherwise a normal merge, except that certain (old) commits do not ever get merged from "proto4" to "master".

I can think of couple of ways to achieve this:

1. I could simply always cherry pick the new commits from "proto4" into "master". However, this I'll need to remember to do every time I'm backporting changes, and forgetting it results in a mess.
2. I could merge "proto4" to "master", and then revert the hardware related commits from "proto4" in "master", i.e. undo the changes. I will need to dig through the commit log to find those changes, but it should be doable.

Option 2. seems like a not-unreasonable way to go about this, since it's a one time trouble and only a one time opportunity for error. However, I feel like there should be a simpler way, where I don't have to manually pick out the correct commits to revert?

P.S.: I'm of course also going to rename the branches, but that seems to be covered by [Switch branch names in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848/switch-branch-names-in-git), and maybe even better by https://mohitgoyal.co/2018/04/07/swap-master-branch-with-another-branch-in-git/

Comment: So, if I understood properly, at the moment, your `master` corresponds to a specific hardware, and the `proto#` branches contain the delta of changes to make it work on their own hardware (so I guess removing the code for `master`'s hardware and adding some specific code - maybe even a single line - for their own hardware). And as the versions evolve, the "production" one changes (from proto2 to proto3 to proto4 etc etc). And you would like a more long term solution to manage this situation? To maintain the main code, while updating your different protos?

Comment: @padawin That's one way to put it, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this:

First, take the diff between current heads of "proto4" and "master":

```
git diff proto4..master > diff.txt
```

Then merge "proto4" into "master", i.e. now "master" is what used to be "proto4". Step one completed, including the renaming. Then create a new branch "proto2", and checkout "proto2". Now apply the previously created diff:

```
git apply diff.txt
```

and commit the changes, with the appropriate message, i.e. "recreated proto2 firmware" etc.

Finally, as a cleanup step you can remove the now unneeded "proto4" branch (you can double check that `diff master proto4` is empty).

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible for you to have the following:

- Consider master as the generic code,
- have a `proto#` branch per hardware, with their specific needs, all based on top of `master`,
- when master changes, either rebase the proto branches on top of it (will imply force push and good communication between the devs), or merge master in each of them (will make a less clean log, and makes it harder to see in a glance what is specific for the `proto` branch)
- maybe have the production proto branch named as `production-proto#` to know quickly which one is the prod one

So each hardware can have its own code, and master is the generic part only.

When you want to create a new hardware, you create a new branch from `master`.

And when you want to discontinue a hardware, it's just a matter of deleting its branch.

Comment: Well, that's not really any better than what I have now, since the "master" branch won't be compilable or testable. I'll have to change branches and merge every time to test a change.

Comment: I see, indeed. I will really speak out of my league on this one, so bear with me :D
Could you have all the versions together, but each hardware specific parts in separate directories, and when you compile, use different instructions (e.g. `make proto3` will compile the code in `common/` and `proto3`; `make proto4` will compile the code in `common/` and `proto4`; and so on). So you would remove quite a few headaches with the versioning? Again, it's a long shot, not knowing the project.

Comment: Well, that's a bit more possible, but on the other hand I'd like the effect on the current "production" branch to be the smallest possible, since that's where I'll anyway do most of my development. Also, applying this to the existing project would certainly be more trouble than just doing the merge/reverts I described as option 2. in my question.